# Find solution of $\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}=-\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Problem**: Find solution of  $$\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}=-\sin x$$
>
> **Solution**:Integrating both sides with respect to $t$
>
> $$\frac {dx}{dt}=-t\sin x +c_1$$
>
> Again integrating ,we get
>
> $$ x=\frac {-t^2 \sin x}{2} +tc_1+c_2$$

Am I doing right ?

Here answer is $x(t)=acost +bsint$ where $a,b$ are constants.

Comment: Since $x=x(t)$ it is not necessarily the case that $\int f(x)dt$ is $f(x)t$.

Comment: @rst It sounds like from your comments that you're supposed to use an appropriate approximation for $\sin x$ when $x$ is very small, and then solve the corresponding ODE. Try solving the ODE $\ddot{x} = - x$, noting that $\sin x$ is very close to $x$ for $x$ sufficiently small.

Comment: @ABlumenthal,you are right.In that case ,we will get the ans.thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integrating $\sin x$ with respect to $t$ does **not** give $t\sin x$ since $x$ depends on $t$. To see why, note that the derivative with respect to $t$ of $t\sin x$ is $(t\sin x)'=\sin x+tx'\cos x$, not $\sin x$.

The equation to be solved implies that $2x'x''=-2x'\sin x$ hence $(x')^2=2\cos x+C$. From here things depend on $C$. For example if $C=2$, $x'=\pm2\cos(x/2)$ hence
$$
\pm t=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{2\cos(x/2)}=\int\frac{\mathrm d(\sin(x/2))}{1-\sin^2(x/2)}=\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+\sin(x/2)}{1-\sin(x/2)}\right)+C,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
x=\pm2\arcsin\tanh(t+C).
$$

Comment: But answer is $x(t)=acost +bsint$ where $a,b$ are constants

Comment: In question $x$ denote angle of displacement.We need solution for sufficiently small angles of displacement

Comment: The function $x(t)=a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)$ does not satisfy the differential equation except if $a=b=0$.

Comment: Could you explain how you got $(x')^2=2\cos x+C$? It seems to me that you dropped $x'$ from $-2x'\sin x$.

Comment: @L.Xu $2x'x''$ is the derivative of $(x')^2$ and $-2x'\sin x$ is the derivative of $2\cos x$. Hence...

Answer (score 2):

Here, I assume the ODE as the below one:
$$y''(x)+\sin(y(x))=0$$ Now, use the following way:

> If $F(y,y',y'')=0$ is the OE which is free of variable $x$, so by setting $y'=u$ we have $$y'=u\frac{du}{dx}$$ according to the Chain Rule and so we have $$F\left(y,u,u\frac{du}{dx}\right)=0$$

Look at the ODE and use above approach. It seems the way you did is not right here. :-)

Comment: $\ddot \smile \;+^1\quad$ I miss you, my friend. How's the internet situation?

Comment: @amWhy: Me too Amy. The conditions remained unchanged and it seems, I need someone like Obama to do it. But I can be on just for few seconds. At least to have a visit of my friends' posts. :-)

Comment: You are a dear...I hope your internet connection improves, since I miss visiting more of *your* posts!